# scala combination of sequences

Tags: scala, functional-programming

How can I sort of flattop this:

```
(Seq(1,2,3,4,5), 
  Seq(Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0),
    Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0), 
    Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)), 
  Seq("a", "b", "c"))
  .zipped.map((a,b,c) => (a,b,c))
```

to instead of receiving:

```
List((1,List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0),a), (2,List(1.0, 2.0
```

getting:

```
List((1,List(1.0),a), (1,List(2.0),a)(1,List(3.0),a)(1,List(4.0),a)(1,List(5.0),a)(2,List(1.0, 2.0
```

Comment: Your expected output abruptly ends with "2.0"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
val s = (Seq(1,2,3,4,5), 
  Seq(Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0),
    Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0), 
    Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)), 
  Seq("a", "b", "c"))
  .zipped
  .flatMap{ case (n, seq, c) =>
    seq.map(s => (n, List(s), c))
  }

println(s)
```

Produces the following output (up to indentation):

```
List(
  (1,List(1.0),a), (1,List(2.0),a), (1,List(3.0),a), (1,List(4.0),a), (1,List(5.0),a), 
  (2,List(1.0),b), (2,List(2.0),b), (2,List(3.0),b), (2,List(4.0),b), (2,List(5.0),b), 
  (3,List(1.0),c), (3,List(2.0),c), (3,List(3.0),c), (3,List(4.0),c), (3,List(5.0),c)
)
```

---

Note that the following much shorter and clearer `for`-comprehension produces exactly the same output:

```
for {
  (n, c) <- Seq(1, 2, 3) zip Seq("a", "b", "c")
  s <- Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
} yield {
  (n, List(s), c)
}
```

Comment: I like the for comprehension. However the real data is not static (like you outlined) but rather different ... i.e. a real sequence of sequences - I only get the more complex expression to work.